# How to store finger print scanner data to sdcard using arduino?

Tags: arduino, cpu-architecture, fingerprint, arduino-ide, arduino-due

I'm using Finger Print Sensor (R305). I want to store finger prints to sdcard using arduino but i don't know how to do it, because finger prints are stored in internal memory of sensor.

Comment: What do you try ? How ? please share your code

Comment: "finger prints are stored in internal memory of sensor."  well seen ;) The adafruit library does not expose this functionality (neither reading nor storing) Not sure if the sensor would do it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [Adafruit Fingerprint Library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library)

In source code, there's exemple to enroll fingerprint:
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library/blob/master/examples/enroll/enroll.ino

You could get Image of Fingerprint with method `Adafruit_Fingerprint::getImage` from https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library/blob/master/Adafruit_Fingerprint.cpp

Comment: yes i have looked at liberary with method Adafruit_Fingerprint::getImage but  i still don't know how to give address of sdcard so data can directly be store in to sdcard and in example you have mentioned i have tried my best but i haven't find the way to do that